# Qual è il significato di "scarabocchiata" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Un matrimonio in provincia* della Marchesa Colombi (pseudonimo di Maria Antonietta Torriani) ho letto:

> C'è l'uso in tutto il Novarese, di mandare in giro il giorno della mezza quaresima una sega. Nel popolo la fanno portare **scarabocchiata** col gesso sul dorso, o rinvoltata e nascosta ingegnosamente, in modo che chi la porta non se ne accorga.

Ho cercato il significato di "scarabocchiare" in alcuni dizionari, ma tutte le accezioni che ho trovato si riferiscono alla scrittura, cosa che non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa che portavano la sega "scarabocchiata col gesso sul dorso"?

Comment: Disegnata con il gesso sulla schiena di qualcuno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non importa che la sega sia reale: può anche essere *scarabocchiata* (cioè disegnata alla buona) sulla schiena di qualcuno con il gesso.

Answer (score 1):

Anche se si tratta di un disegno, che viene fatto necessariamente di volata per non farsi accorgere dal 'supporto', 'scarabocchiata' mi sembra proprio una bella scelta nella frase citata. 'Schizzata', 'tracciata', 'tratteggiata' potevano essere altre scelte plausibili ma 'scarabocchiata' riassume in una sola parola: 'disegnata di corsa e di nascosto in un momento rubato al volo'. 'Scarabocchio' viene usato, tuttavia, anche per indicare i tracciati senza senso o incomprensibili lasciati dai bambini più piccoli con una matita su un foglio di carta, non necessariamente simboli riconoscibili.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!